# Neural Network classifier with low accuracy does not improve when changing neuron count

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I made a neural network to recognize objects, I trained this model using 7 categories of images. When I train this model, I always get the accuracy of 0.217. Even I changed each count of neuron of each layers, still I get the accuracy of 0.217

[categories of training image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmMWM.png)
(I used open cv to convert images to arrays and  used pickle to store datasets)

'create data set'

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import pickle
import random


datadir = r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Tenserflow\upgrade1\Images"

categories = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(datadir, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        categories.append(name)


training_data = []
img_size = 100

def create_training_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(datadir, category)
        class_num = categories.index(category)

        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size, img_size))
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
           
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_training_data()
random.shuffle(training_data)


x =[]
y =[]

for features ,label in training_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)

x = np.array(x).reshape(-1,  img_size, img_size, 1)
y = np.array(y)


file1 = open('x.pickle', 'wb')
file2 = open('y.pickle', 'wb')


pickle.dump(x, file1)
pickle.dump(y, file2)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

'training code'

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np

x =pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb"))
y =pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

x = x/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(3,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(7,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(7,(3,3)))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs = 2, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Comment: Is your data balanced or can you post your data size like how many samples of each class are present

Comment: use ImageDataGenerator to process images and for augmentation. I think network is not training because of the simple architecture,use bigger channels for conv layers like (32 or 16) and (256,512) for dense. https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/

Comment: i used about 28000 images ,dataset is over 200mb

Comment: Thank you ..!!! I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues in your code:

1: you use `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss. This loss assumes that the targets are in format `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0]`, `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` etc but your dataset creation seems to have the targets as `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` etc.

Either you need to switch to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss and single output feature or use `to_categorical` function for your targets. I would suggest using the `to_categorical` function so you don't need to change your network.

More info on those:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical

2: Your network is far too simple to give you a good accuracy. You use far too few filters in your `Conv2D`. Try using 16, 32 and 32 filters for example. Also your `Dense` layer is far too small. Try using 128 for the first and 7 for the second dense layer.